# create a random colour image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV. I am trying to create a random color image. Firstly I tried to create a random grayscale image. The code I have attached below

```
void random_colour(Mat input_image) {
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
            image.at<uchar>(i,j)= rand()%255;
    imwrite("output.tif",image);
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat img=Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
    random_colour(img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The output obtained is

[image]

Now I changed my above code to create a random colour image as.

```
void random_colour(Mat input_image) {
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = rand()%255;
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = rand()%255;
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = rand()%255;
         }
    }
    imwrite("output.tif",image);
}
```

The main function remains same. While doing so, I get a runtime error. Please help me on what should I do. What I understood is that each pixel in colour space has three component RGB. So therefore I am changing all the three component of each pixel. I am not getting the output what I wanted.

Comment: Why not use [`cv::randu`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#randu)? e.g. `cv::randu(image, 0, 256);` | "The main function remains same." -- in that case you create a 1 channel image and then try to access it as if it was a 3 channel image.

Comment: What error you get? Please post the error trace so we can help. Also, as far as I know OpenCV handles `BGR` values instead of `RGB` , be careful with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line creates a greyscale image, it doesn't have three channels.

```
 Mat img=Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
```

That means when you use this line, its going to crash:

```
 image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = rand()%255;
```

You need to not use CV_8UC1 because that creates 1 channel (C1) try it with CV_8UC3 instead

```
Mat img=Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC3);
```

FYI 8u means 8 bit so values 0 to 255, CX is the number of channels in the image. If you want BGR you need C3.

Answer (score 21):

no need to reinvent the wheel, please use [cv::randu()](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga1ba1026dca0807b27057ba6a49d258c0)

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
    randu(img, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    imshow("random colors image", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]